# Solr for indexing application log files

Tags: search, lucene, solr, logging

I am thinking of using solr to index the log files generated by applications and allow the support staff to serach the log for trouble shooting. Any body ever did this kind of thing using solr?

Comment: I met some folks who are doing this, and hope to have more details to publish soon.

Comment: Is Solr the best fit for this problem? You need the faceting, the full-text search (because your logs aren't at all regular), and you don't need the set operations of a regular RDBMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rackspace uses Hadoop and Solr to index terabytes of log data:

http://highscalability.com/how-rackspace-now-uses-mapreduce-and-hadoop-query-terabytes-data